# protein in the rest days

Tags: diet, protein, weight-gain

I don't take protein - not even 1g on my rest days. On workout days I eat protein, more calories, etc. Should I also eat protein on my rest days?

Answer (score 5):

It's not like your protein intake on rest days is actually zero (unless you eat **NOTHING** on your rest days). I assume you are talking about a supplement source like whey protein.

It is considered a good practice to consume almost the same amount of whey on rest days as you do on the days you workout. Building muscles is an easy but long process. Your muscles develop overtime and it's necessary that you keep on taking the important nutrients for that (protein being one of them).

It's not like if you don't workout today, the protein needs of your body will decrease. It's advisable to take the same amount of calories, proteins and carbs. Or on rest days you can go with other protein sources like oats, chicken etc.

Watch this [Talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tM1LFFxeKg) for more information on how muscles grow.